# PHP: Create anonymous class with function result

Tags: php

When generating an object this way AND executing a method, PHP gives an error.

```
class A {

    static public function b() {

        $o = new get_called_class();                  // works

        $class = get_called_class();
        $o = new $class;                              // works

        $o = (new $class)->method();                  // works

        $o = (new get_called_class())->method();      // doesn't work
        // error message: Class '...\get_called_class' not found

        $o = (new (get_called_class()))->method();    // doesn't work
        // error message: syntax error, unexpected '('
    }
}
```

Why does the last lines fail?

How to write it in one line?

Comment: The other lines do not work either. You have missing `;` and undefined class `get_called_class`

Comment: Ok, edited. thanks. But that does not solve the problem :-(

Comment: @MarkusZeller None of my quedtions were answered. Looking still for an answer to both of my questions.

Comment: It is simply answered by "If you want to use an instance, store it in a variable."

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately you can't do it directly with the function's return value, but you can save it into a variables and use the variable. You can also use `static` or `self` constants.

```
$class = get_called_class();
$o = (new $class())->method();
$o = (new static())->method();
$o = (new self())->method();
```

Answer (score 1):

Not possible at all. If you want to use an instance, store it in a variable.

```
class MyClass {
     public function method(): string {
          return "Hello World";
     }
}

$instance = new MyClass();
$result = $instance->method();
```

You could work around if you do not need an instance by using a static method.

```
class MyClass {
     public static function method(): string {
          return "Hello World";
     }
}

$result = MyClass::method();
```