# How do I do create an instance of the same class that the method belongs to?

Tags: php, oop

Is there a variable/magic Property that contains "this class" inside a class, for purposes of `new`?

I want:

```
trait foo {

    public function __construct( $x ) {
        // ... do stuff ...
    }

    static function init( $x ) {
        return new __THISCLASS__( $x ); // <--- whuzzat?
    }

)

class A {
    use foo;
}

class B {
    use foo;
}
```

The reason I'm doing this is that the function is actually contained in a Trait that is used by multiple classes, so I need the common code to be able to figure out what class it's running in and create the corresponding object.

`A::init()` should return an `A` object, and `B::init()` a `B` object.

Running PHP 7.3

Comment: `new self()` and `new static()` should work. In normal methods you can also use `new $this()`.

Comment: I found some useful info for you to read, [in the PHP manual of all the odd and unexpected places](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.constants.predefined.php)

Comment: `__CLASS__` does not work.  `self` does.

Comment: scratch that -- `self` does not appear to "propagate" through extended classes.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57118056/php-create-anonymous-class-with-function-result/57118228#57118228

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe the easiest and most readable way to accomplish something like this would be to use `static` to take advantage of [late static binding](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.late-static-bindings.php).

E.g.:

```php
trait aTrait {
    public static function build($x) {
        return new static($x);   
    }
}

class A
{
    public function __construct($x) {
        $this->x = $x;
    }
    use aTrait;
}

class B
{
    public function __construct($x) {
        $this->x = $x * 2;
    }

    use aTrait;
}


$a = A::build(2);
$b = B::build(2);
var_dump($a);
var_dump($b);
```

See it working [here](https://3v4l.org/BogSt).

`get_called_class()` is simply a convenience for this. As [the manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.get-called-class.php) says:

> get_called_class — The "Late Static Binding" class name

I wouldn't use `__CLASS__` or `self` for builder methods, since these always refer to the class they were originally used on. If you later on extend the class, the method wouldn't work as you would expect.

For example, something like this:

```php
trait dangerTrait
{
    public static function build($x) {
        return new self($x);
    }
}

class X
{
    use dangerTrait;

    public function __construct($x) {
        $this->x = $x * 3;
        echo "building class ", __CLASS__, "\n";
    }
}

class Y extends X {

    public function __construct($x) {
        $this->x = $x * 4;
        echo "building class ", __CLASS__, "\n";
    }
}

$x = X::build(2);
$y = Y::build(2);
```

...would output:

```
building class X
building class X
```

and both `$x` and `$y` would be instances of `X`.

Comment: `self` vs `static`: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5197300/new-self-vs-new-static

Comment: That's why I say I wouldn't use `self` (or `__CLASS__`). Have I missed something?

Comment: Not at all -- just a useful note for myself or others coming across this later

Answer (score 2):

You can get class which uses trait with [get_called_class()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.get-called-class.php) function. For example

```
trait Foo
{
    public static function init()
    {
        $class = get_called_class();
        return new $class();
    }
}


class A {
    use Foo;
}

$obj = A::init();
```

Another way is the usage of [Late Static Bindings](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.late-static-bindings.php)